# Entity Framework with Castle Windsor IoC Container - Validation Error

Tags: entity-framework, castle-windsor, mvp

I am using MVP, with EntityFramework and an implementation of Castle Windsor.

Everything seems fine however when adding a new record into a table (which has a number of Foreign Keys mapping it to other tables), using dbContext.SaveChanges(), the EntityFramework seems to go on and attempt inserting records in every other table with a foreign key in the immediate table.

For example: **Employee** table has a foreign key which is linking it to the **Department** table. When EF is asked to SaveChanges() on the **Employee** table; it goes on to insert an empty record in the **Department** table, which is not required and this is triggering this exception:

***Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.***

I have 'catched' the details of this exception using this:

```
            catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
            {
                foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
                        //For QuickWatch
                        //((System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException)$exception).EntityValidationErrors.First().ValidationErrors.First().ErrorMessage
                    }
                }
            }
```

The problem seemed to be happening at the time of saving changes; when Windsor Castle has already instantiated 'objects' for every entity. These instances are making EF think that they're there to be saved into the db, which is causing validation error since there no data is being sent into any of these tables.

What can I do to solve this problem. Will creating a base class for the Entity Model help? and if yes, how can I do that?

Please let me know. Thanks.

**Update**

@Steven Dependencies are not being injected into entities. Entities are being injected into the Presenters (in the constructor). What is happening is that because Deparment has a 'Navigation Property' in Employee, everytime I insert a new employee EntityFramework inserts a blank department with it (in the Department table) and thus generating the validation exception, because no data is being sent for the Department obviously!

Comment: What dependencies do you inject into your entities?

Comment: @Steven I have answered in the **Update**, in the question itself.

Comment: So why don't you `new` the Employee in the Presenter?

Comment: @Steven This would solve the problem I have tried this, but doesn't meet the requirement on me to have everything injected through Windsor. I am aware that creating a base class for the Entities is a solution for this; one which would manage 'Lifestyles' or 'Lifecycles' of entities. I just do not know how to do that.

Comment: I'm afraid that you misunderstand Dependency Injection, because it is not meant to let the container resolve every instance. Take a look at [this article](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/09/30/to-new-or-not-to-new/) that does a fairly good job in explaining what to resolve and what to new up yourself.

Comment: @Steven Thank you for the information and for posting the link, it is now clear for me and I no longer have this issue. Kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Castle Windsor does *implicit property injection* by default, which means that it will try to inject every public property on the type that's being created. When an `Employee` has a `Department` property, it will try to create a `Department` instance and if it succeeds, it will inject it into that property. This is clearly what's happening here.

You should use your IoC container **only** for building up object graphs of **services**, not entities. Don't do that.

Comment: Do you mean to inject entities outside Windsor? Do you think it is worth trying to 'turn off' implicit property injection on Windsor; i.e., will it work?

Comment: It's worth trying **not** to use your DI container to create entities. If they need dependencies, pass them in using method injection on the methods that use those dependencies.